# Yii2 get product id seperated by comma

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, yii2, implode

I have followed this guy tutorial

and got total price of all products and now I have created a table called order which contains (total_price and product) columns
now I want what all products ID which are selected (added to cart) separated by comma and be saved into

```
$model= new orders ()
$model->product (product id added in cart separated by comma)in db
```

I've saved `total_price` in db through controller though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to save comma seprated data in DB

**implode()** function returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order

```
$model= new orders ();
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$model->product = implode(', ', $array);
$model->save();
```

**explode()** function returns an array of strings.

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
explode(', ', $string);
```

Comment: $array is not static it should get value of product id  when i add to cart then implode function is used but i dont know how to get the value of product id from session

Comment: Refer [Yii2 Session and Cookies](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies)