# Yii2 store product id seperated by comma

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-basic-app, implode

I want to add proid in $model->product which is in different table I want to get product id that are added into cart and store them in the DB(phpmyadmin) seperated by comma

controller.php(where i get session from)

```
class CartController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public $totalItems=0;
    public $totalPrice=0.00;
    //public $netPrice = 0;

    public function actionAdd($id = null)
    {
        if(!intval($id) || empty($id)){
           Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','cannot find this product');
            return $this->redirect('/front');

        }

        if(!isset(Yii::$app->session['cart'])){
            Yii::$app->session['cart'] = [];
            Yii::$app->session['total_items'] = 0;
            Yii::$app->session['total_price'] = 0.00;

        }
           $this->addtocart($id);

           $this->setTotal();
           //$model = new Orders();
           //$model->ordername = ;
              // $model->ordertotal = $netPrice ;
            return $this->redirect('index');


    }
    public function addtocart($id){
        if(isset(Yii::$app->session['cart'][$id])){
            $session = Yii::$app->session['cart'];
            $session[$id]= $session[$id] +=1;
            Yii::$app->session['cart']= $session;
        }
        else{
            $session = Yii::$app->session['cart'];
            $session[$id] = 1;
            Yii::$app->session['cart'] = $session;
        }
    }
    public function setTotal(){
        Yii::$app->session['total_items']=$this->totalItems(Yii::$app->session['cart']);
        Yii::$app->session['total_price']=$this->totalPrice(Yii::$app->session['cart']);

        $this->totalItems = Yii::$app->session['total_items'];
        $this->totalPrice = Yii::$app->session['total_price'];





    }
    public function totalItems($cart){
        $totalItems = 0;
        if(is_array($cart)){
            foreach ($cart as $id=>$qty){
                $totalItems += $qty;
            }

            return $totalItems;
        }
        //return $totalItems;
    }
    public function totalPrice($cart){
        $netPrice = 0.00;
        if(is_array($cart)){
            foreach ($cart as $id=>$qty){
                $item = $this->findProduct($id);
                $netPrice += $item->price * $qty;
            }
            //return $netPrice;
        }
        return $netPrice;
    }


    public function findProduct($id){
        return Products::findOne($id);
    }
    public function updateCart(){
        foreach(Yii::$app->session['cart'] as $id=>$qty){
            if(isset($_POST[$id])){
                if($_POST == 0){
                    $session = Yii::$app->session['cart'];
                    unset($session[$id]);
                    Yii::$app->session['cart'] = $session;
                }
                else{
                    $cart = Yii::$app->session['cart'];
                    $cart[$id] = $_POST[$id];
                    Yii::$app->session['cart'] = $cart;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if(!isset(Yii::$app->session['cart']) || empty(Yii::$app->session['cart'])){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','cart is empty');

        }
// i made a table named order with colums ordertotal and products where ordertotal should store the total value and products should store the product id which are added to cart got the order total but didn't get products
            $model = new Orders();
            $model->ordertotal = $this->totalPrice(Yii::$app->session['cart']); //got the order total from this 
           //$model->product=add the product id( <?= Html::a('AddToCart',['/cart/add','id'=> $p->proid], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?> //this is my product page where i 'add to cart' from) seperated by comma

        if($model->save()){
            print_r('ok');

        }
        else{
           echo $model->getErrors();

        }



        return $this->render('index',[
            'totalItems' => $this->totalItems(Yii::$app->session['cart']),
            'totalPrice' => $this->totalPrice(Yii::$app->session['cart']),
        ]);
    }

}
```

i got the above code from t=PLX5MZfWdby5QFDLU-Ov7Ixv6AilU-mgcQ"

implementing new model and adding it to db is my implemtation

product.php

```
<?php foreach ($product as $p) { ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <h2><?php echo $p->name?></h2>
                    <?php echo "<br/>"?>
                    <?php echo "Name: ".$p->name?>
                    <?php echo "<br/>"?>


                     <?php echo "price: ".$p->price?>
                    <?php echo "<br/>"?>
                    <?= Html::a('AddToCart',['/cart/add','id'=> $p->proid], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>



                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 get product id seperated by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075003/yii2-get-product-id-seperated-by-comma)

Answer (score 0):

You must alter serveral functions, first need to alter addtocart function.

adding `Yii::$app->session['cart']['id'][] = $id;`

Comment: do i need to add that function in addtocart($id) function? then am getting this error
Indirect modification of overloaded element of yii\web\Session has no effect

Comment: $session is object, not array. $session['the_variable'] is overload $session->get('the_variable')

Comment: could you please re-write the above code as i am new to yii2 and php